# Vuejs fusioncharts have completely transparent background

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

I'm using FusionCharts with Vue 2, everything is working fine. I just want my charts to have completely transparent background so that background color of component behind them will show through. I've tried with different values of `bgColor` and `bgAlpha` in my chart settings but nothing seems to work how to do this? Here's my chart object:

```
data2Src() {
  return {
    chart: {
      caption: "Total User Count",
      subcaption: "",
      xaxisname: "User Groups",
      yaxisname: "Number of users",
      bgColor: "#DDDDDD",
      bgAlpha: "0",
      theme: "gammel"
    },
    data: this.chart2Data
  };
```

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Comment: `bgAlpha` should be `0`? `0` means transparent. For instance: https://jsfiddle.net/mwo70f4j/

Comment: No even if I set`bgAlpha` to `0` its still the same. See updated question

Comment: Not sure. It's better you can check the CSS on what you rendered and it's background via developer tool. It's possible your background div is white and opaque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using css, sometime the config from library is not enough, making us need to put some css hack

```
<div id="c">
  <div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
</div>




 #chart-container {
  svg {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
}
```

Check out this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nxorg6j0/